# What header should I include for memcpy and realloc?

Tags: c++, objective-c, header, memcpy, realloc

I am porting a project to the iPhone and it uses `realloc` and `memcpy` which are not found. What is the header to include?

It's a project mixing Objective C and C++ and I am starting to be lost.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In C:

```
#include <string.h> // memcpy
#include <stdlib.h> //realloc
```

In C++, remove the `.h` and prefix with a `c`. In C++, they will be placed in the `std` namespace, but are also global.

Comment: You could use `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#else` to automatically include the correct ones for either C or C++.

Comment: If you don't mind polluting the global namespace, `string.h` and `stdlib.h` work in C++ just as well and you can keep using `realloc`, `memcpy` instead of `std::realloc`, `std::memcpy` etc., which seems to be more in line with what the original poster wanted.

Answer (score 8):

In C++ it's more idiomatic to use `std::copy` than C's `memcpy`, although the latter does work just as well. To get `std::copy`, you need to `#include <algorithm>`.

There's not a direct C++ equivalent to `realloc`, though.

Comment: If I could mark this answer as not useful with a comment, I would do so because it is incorrect.  As GMan said, realloc is found in <cstdlib>.

Comment: I did not say that it is not possible to use the C standard library function `realloc` in C++ (since, of course, the C++ standard library includes the entirety of the C89 standard library). I said that there is not a new C++ standard library function that encompasses the functionality of `realloc` as `std::copy` does for `memcpy`. Although I suppose my intent is not obvious if my answer is read in isolation as opposed to in conjunction with the other, already accepted answer.