# Memcpy Error Include

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to run the program in Visual Studio 2013
The `malloc` function is not recognized, I don't know what header should I include if not `cstring`

```
#include <cstring>

float x[4] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 };
float y[4] = { 2, 2, 2, 2 };

float* total = malloc(8 * sizeof(float)); // array to hold the result

memcpy(total,     x, 4 * sizeof(float)); // copy 4 floats from x to total[0]...total[3]
memcpy(total + 4, y, 4 * sizeof(float)); // copy 4 floats from y to total[4]...total[7]
```

Comment: #include <stdlib.h> helped with malloc, memcpy still not recognised

Comment: `<cstring>` is a C++ header (based on the standard C header `<string.h>`). Are you compiling your code as C or as C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What header should I include for memcpy and realloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283712/what-header-should-i-include-for-memcpy-and-realloc)

Answer (score 4):

The `memcpy` function is declared in `<string.h>`.

The `malloc` function is declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Your system *should* have some documentation that tells you, for each library function, which header you need to `#include` to use it (and possibly what library you have to specify to link to it). (If you were on Unix or Linux, I'd suggest the man page.) Failing that, a web search for the function name will probably give you the information (though there's also plenty of *bad* information out there).

For MS Windows, MSDN has a lot of online documentation. For example, a Google search for "MSDN malloc" turns up [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx) -- which, unfortunately, also mentions the non-standard `<malloc.h>` header, without making it clear that it's non-standard.

A web search for "man malloc" will give you results that might be more Unix-specific, but for the standard functions that shouldn't be much of a problem.

Incidentally, `<cstring>` is a C++ header; it's the C++ version of C's `<string.h>`. If you want to write C code, be sure you're invoking your compiler as a C compiler. (Naming your source file with a `.c` extension is sometimes enough to do this.)

Answer (score 1):

If you Google a standard library function you can usually find a page, such as [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) one, that will tell you which header to include.

`#include <string.h>`

`void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`